# Panda Dataframe Copy to another dataframe actually copy the data type?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I try to copy a dataframe to another dataframe using default 'deep' copy method. But when i try to do some calculation in the second dataframe it is showing me result in datatype 'int64'. Is there any way to show this in real format(float64)?

```
dilution_category_info
```

Output

```
IS_HIGH_VALUE   0   1
DIALUTION_CATEGORY      
0   93117   107300
1   374679  628604
2   64642   192098
3   404921  823262
4   145663  322063   


dilution_category_info_2 = dilution_category_info.copy()
dilution_category_info_2[0][0] = (dilution_category_info[0][0]/(dilution_category_info[0][0]\
                                          + dilution_category_info[1][0]))
```

Output

```
IS_HIGH_VALUE   0   1
DIALUTION_CATEGORY      
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

At first type cast the datatype of your new deep copied dataframe explicitely as (assuming you have numpy available as np, if not import it as `import numpy as np` for my code below to work):

```
dilution_category_info_2 = dilution_category_info.copy()    
dilution_category_info_2[0][0] = dilution_category_info_2.astype(np.float64)
```

then assign the values as :

```
dilution_category_info_2[0][0] = (dilution_category_info[0][0]/(dilution_category_info[0][0]+ dilution_category_info[1][0]))
```